# Finding Text String Without a Pattern and Returning Text that was Found in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have a data frame that has a column with strings of text. Within those strings I want to pull out certain key words. They may appear once, more than once, or never within each string. I want R to return a new column that contains those key words if they were found.

Below is my theoretical example

```
#Opinions on Color
v <- c("red is cool", "I prefer blue", "yellow is better than blue", "orange is controversial", "what are colors", "sometimes I like pink and sometimes it's blue")

#Pull out Color Discussed
text <- paste0(c("red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "pink"), collapse = '|')

What I expect:
[1] "red"    "blue"    "yellow,Blue"     "orange"    "NA"      "pink,blue"
```

I have been trying to make use of grepl. I tried the below code which returns what I want for just "red" but I am struggling to make it return the unique color for all colors.

```
ifelse((grepl("red",v)), "red", "NA")

[1] "red" "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"
```

I also tried making use of the if()else() statement but that runs into the error "Error in if : if the condition has a length of >1"

```
if(grepl("red",v)){paste("red")
}else if(grepl("blue",v)){paste("blue")
}else{paste("NA")}`
```

My last thought was trying to find a way to locate the position of the key word in the string and then extracting the word at that position but I haven't found an elegant way of doing that yet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can exctract the desired words, then paste them with `toString`, and finally replace empty chars with NAs

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

v %>%
    map_vec(str_extract_all, text) %>%
    map_vec(toString) %>%
    replace(., . == "", NA)

[1] "red"          "blue"         "yellow, blue"
[4] "orange"       NA             "pink, blue"
```

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution:

```r
v <- c("red is cool", "I prefer blue", "yellow is better than blue", 
       "orange is controversial", "what are colors", 
       "sometimes I like pink and sometimes it's blue")

matches <- gregexpr("red|blue|yellow|orange|pink", v)

sapply(regmatches(v, matches), \(x) if(length(x)) paste0(x, collapse=", ") else NA) 
#> [1] "red"          "blue"         "yellow, blue" "orange"       NA            
#> [6] "pink, blue"
```

Comment: you can use simply `sapply(regmatches(v, matches),  paste0, collapse=", ")` but will obtain empty string instead of NA.

Answer (score 2):

Add word boundary markers to the regex so that, for example, "red" does not match "fred" and then use `strapplyc` to pull out the matches and use `toString` to combine them into comma-separated strings.  Finally convert "" to NA.

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- paste0("\\b(", text, ")\\b")
strapplyc(v, pat, engine = "R") |> 
  sapply(toString) |> 
  sub("^$", NA, x = _)

## [1] "red"          "blue"         "yellow, blue" "orange"       NA            
## [6] "pink, blue"
```

Answer (score 2):

in Base R, using Regex:

```r
sapply(`is.na<-`(x <- regmatches(v, gregexpr(text, v)), !lengths(x)), toString)
[1] "red"          "blue"         "yellow, blue" "orange"       "NA"          
[6] "pink, blue"
```

Another option

```r
pat <- sprintf("(\\b ?(?!%s)\\w+\\W*)+", text)
x <- trimws(gsub(pat, ",", v, perl=TRUE),,',')
is.na(x) <- !nzchar(x)
x
#> [1] "red"         "blue"        "yellow,blue" "orange"      NA           
#> [6] "pink,blue"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>